# Bash - Extract string between (multiple) tokens

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have tried to find answers for this issue all over stackoverflow, but just got more confused...

I need to extract a string from between 2 tokens, as follows:

```
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>5432542-gfd5432g-543254g-432g53</string>
```

what I need is the digits-letters-hyphens string between `<string>` and `</string>`. The problem is that these tokens appear thousands of times in the file - therefore I think I must include `<key>UUID</key>` as well.

I assume answers will include `sed`, `awk` and regular expressions, and if possible - I would love a short explanation about what's suggested.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Looks like some XML to me, in which case this could be achieved using an XPath.

Answer (score 0):

If it always follows `<key>UUID</key>` you can use `grep`

```
grep '<key>UUID</key>' -A 1 file | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's:<string>::' -e 's:</string>::'
```

1) grep line containing  `<key>UUID</key>` , and ( `-A 1` ) one line after the string
2) tail: from the output only take the last line
3) sed: replace `<string>` and `</string>` with nothing (-e for multiple patterns)